# disable the Android Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I've made a keyboard for Android, and I want to disable the Android Keyboard to use only my keyboard. How can I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do disable softkeyboard.

[Disable Softkeyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

If by "keyboard for Android", you mean an input method editor, you cannot "disable the Android Keyboard to use only my keyboard". Please allow the user to choose his or her own soft keyboard, which may or may not be yours.

Comment: there are ways to force hide the softkeyboard, but if you want users to use your keyboard, then you should let them install your keyboard and enable it via IME. probably you can give a pop up on start up instructing user to download and install your keyboard.